# Does Monit support multiple email recipients with the same format?

Tags: monit

I use monit to monitor the status of a service,when the service is down, I want to send alert email to multiple recipients with the same format.
here is part of my monit configuration:

```
set mail-format { from: no-reply@gmail.com }
check host hostA with address hostA
  alert userA@gmail.com
  MAIL-FORMAT {     # use local format
     subject: redis is down on hostA
     message:   redis is down on hostA on port 6379

  Yours sincerely,
  monit
  }
  alert userB@gmail.com
  MAIL-FORMAT {     # use local format
     subject: redis is down on hostA
     message:   redis is down on hostA on port 6379

  Yours sincerely,
  monit
  }
  if failed port 6379 retry 3 then exec "/monit/scripts/myscripts.sh"
```

it works but have some redundant things (e.g. the same MAIL-FORMAT for 2 users)
. there will be multiple email formats I will use in the same configuration file.
Dose monit support multiple recipients with the same and only one local email format?

Answer (score 8):

From the official documentation:

> If you want to send alert messages to more email addresses, add a set
>   alert 'email' statement for each address.

Following this, the following configuration should work:

```
set mail-format { from: no-reply@gmail.com }
check host hostA with address hostA
  alert userA@gmail.com
  alert userB@gmail.com
  MAIL-FORMAT {     # use local format
     subject: redis is down on hostA
     message:   redis is down on hostA on port 6379

  Yours sincerely,
  monit
  }
```

Regards

**EDIT:**

The documentation does not state it, but the position of the elements might play a role here. Try to define the alert addresses AFTER the mail-format declaration. Also, note you use two mail-format declaration in your code - If this is not necessary, try to use only one (the latter).

```
set mail-format {
      from: monit@foo.bar
  reply-to: support@domain.com
   subject: $SERVICE $EVENT at $DATE
   message: Monit $ACTION $SERVICE at $DATE on $HOST: $DESCRIPTION.
            Yours sincerely,
            monit
 }
 alert userA@gmail.com
 alert userB@gmail.com
```

Comment: Official documentation: https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/#Setting-an-alert-recipient

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried your configuration before, userA  received an email with global format while userB  received an email with local format.

Comment: documentation has updated: https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Setting-an-alert-recipient